# What use instead of css() for pseudo elements?

Tags: jquery

guys. I have a little problem today... Code is below:

```
var ttw = 10;
$('.insttip:after').css('left',(ttw/2-8)+'px');
```

Of course, it's not working. The reason is that **css() function** adds css property using element's '*style*' attribute. **$('.insttip:after')** is a pseudo element, so it has no '*style*' attribute.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: `$('.insttip:after')` is not a valid jQuery selector.

Comment: You can't select pseudo-elements with JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery

Comment: @James Allardice you can, just not directly.

Comment: This [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery ] might be of some assistance to you.

Comment: @Playmaker: Sadly, in CSS2.1, `attr` was limited to the `content` property. It's been opened up since, but one would need to test ones target browsers.

Comment: @Dave: See Playmaker's comment.

Comment: Temporarily using code below, but I don't like it at all:          $('<style>.insttip:after{left:'+(ttw/2-4)+'px;}</style>').appendTo('head');

Comment: @Georgy Liparteliani if you want a cross-browser solution I'd say that's your best bet IMO.

Comment: What do you get with $('.insttip').next() instead of :after?

Comment: @JamesAllardice - http://jsfiddle.net/4n4Yv/

Answer (score -1):

You can't use pseudo elements in JavaScript. However, if you're looking for a workaround, here is one. Note, however, that this is if you are trying to select a text node:

```
var ttw = 10;
$($(".insttip")[0].nextSibling).appendTo($("<span/>")).css("left",(ttw/2-8) + "px");
```

That will wrap the text in a `<span>` tag, however.